# How to create a URL where the query parameters are saved to some form of DB

Tags: php, html, forms, api

I am looking to create a simple url where I can add URL querys to it and then have these saved to a database.

This would be the format that i'm looking for

example.com?name=value1&email=value2

Could anybody help ?

Comment: What explicitly are you struggeling with right now?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the values on the script from `$_GET`, then put them in your database using PDO or MySQLi. I don't know your database structure so I can't really help any further:

```
// In index.php
echo $_GET["name"];
echo $_GET["email"];

// Put them in your database
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, my final code is below: `<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","dbuser","password","dbname");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO wifi (name, email, voucher)
VALUES
('$_GET[name]','$_GET[email]','$_GET[voucher]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>`

Comment: No bother. Don't forget to escape anything you put into a database though.